# Sanitize filenames in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby, mime-types

To determine the file type of an attached file, I used the OS "file" utility:

```
class AttachedFileTypeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    file = record.resource.uploaded_file
    attached_file = Rails.root + file.path
    file_type = `file #{attached_file}`
    Rails.logger.info "Attached file type determined to be: #{file_type}"
    unless file_type.split(',').first =~ /ASCII|UTF/
      record.errors[:resource_content_type] << "Attachment does not appear to be a text CSV file, please ensure it was saved correctly."
    end
  end
end
```

Unfortunately [brakeman](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman) suggests its a command line injection opportunity.  I'm assuming this means someone figures out a clever name for a file like:

```
; rm -rf /;
```

And away we go.  Whats a good way to sanitize filenames?

Comment: Escape separators? Replace with legal chars like underscores?

Comment: @DaveNewton: replacing with underscores is no good; the file's already uploaded with the given name. There should be a library to do shell-escaping.

Comment: @Len Then it's too late, isn't it. File names should be sanitized before they're written to the file system--the common libraries have hooks to allow this, AFAIK.

Comment: @DaveNewton: no, it isn't. The file is written to the filesystem, and we assume safely so, by whatever library or part of the system that takes uploads. That doesn't change the fact that the filename itself is dangerous if placed into a shell command unescaped.

Comment: @DaveNewton: i.e. if the filename is `abc def` with the space and all, then `\`file #{attached_file}\`` is obviously going to fail, despite the upload handler's ability to create such a file.

Comment: @Len Oh, I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IO#popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen) to call the external command:

```
file_type = IO.popen(['file', attached_file]).read
```

This will handle proper escaping of funny characters in the filename for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution also seems to lead to locking issues in single-threaded environments (like running specs).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834556/jruby-io-popen-read-hangs-in-action-when-requests-are-made-to-the-local-dev-serv